# Definition of a graph schema via XML

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

We have written a python script to load data from different sources in to our Neo4j graph database. One challenge we are facing is that we would need to modify the script every time we come up with a new client whose data we will load. What I want to do is specify a mapping file in XML or something else that the script will read before loading a data source and the subsequent nodes and relationships are then created on the fly based on the definition in this file.

Have any of you done something like that? If Yes, can you please guide me around a format I can use or any tools available for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use Cypher as Mapping language, it's pretty good at expressing complex graph structures and handling updates and create operations.

So, e.g. if your input data is CSV you'd use LOAD CSV, if it is JSON you could use something like this: http://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-load-json-from-url/